# Popup / Alert windows when working with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, popup

The program for ordering statements on the registry, I can not go to their pop-up window, selenium does not see that any new is being created.

Is it possible to do it through Xpath without using the transition to the Popup window, a browser function, or in another way in Selenium (Chrome)?

New window detection function:

```
public static string ClickAndSwitchWindow(IWebElement elementToBeClicked,
        IWebDriver driver, int timer = 2000)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> previousHandles = new
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> currentHandles = new
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            previousHandles.AddRange(driver.WindowHandles);
            elementToBeClicked.Click();

            Thread.Sleep(timer);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                currentHandles.Clear();
                currentHandles.AddRange(driver.WindowHandles);
                foreach (string s in previousHandles)
                {
                    currentHandles.RemoveAll(p => p == s);
                }
                if (currentHandles.Count == 1)
                {
                    driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandles[0]);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    return currentHandles[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The piece of code itself:

```
//After this click of this element, a window opens:
//"Send request"
IWebElement PopWindowsstart =  ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/span")));

//Search for a new window
string newWin = ClickAndSwitchWindow(PopWindowsstart, Browser, 2500);
PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(Browser);
//Switch to a new window
Browser.SwitchTo().Window(newWin);

//Statement Number:
IWebElement NumExctract = ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("div[class='v-label v-label-tipFont tipFont v-label-undef-w'] b")));

//Read check
MessageBox.Show(NumExctract.Text);    

//"Continue work"
ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/span"))).Click();

//"Change"
ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/span"))).Click();

Thread.Sleep(300000);
```

Type window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this a bit easier.

If you need to switch to a popup, try the below.

```
        public static string SwitchToPopup()
    {
        var mainHandle = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        var handles = Driver.WindowHandles;

        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            if (mainHandle == handle)
            {
                continue;
            }
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            break;
        }
        var result = Url;
        return result;

    }
```

When you need to switch back, use:

```
    public static void GoToMainHandle()
    {
        var handles = Driver.WindowHandles;
        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            break;
        }
    }
```

That being said, your xpath is not something that should ever be used. Please look at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp and rewrite it. When you use chrome to give you your xpath like:

```
ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/span"))).Click();
```

If your dev adds a div in here somewhere, all of your tests will now fail. If your devs are not providing unique identifiers, work with them to resolve that. You should have id's, class names etc.

Comment: Thanks, problem was solved earlier, simple negligence, did not notice the erroneous xpath instead of css locator.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static void PopUp()
{
    _webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
}
```